# NetBeans8 Scala on Mac OS X - Cannot detect and install the selected platform

Tags: macos, scala, netbeans

I have set SCALA_HOME & JAVA_HOME and updated netbeans_default_options in netbeans.conf with the absolute path for each environment variable and NetBeans 7 or 8 is still unable to detect Scala Platform on OS X.

SCALA_HOME=/Volumes/MyPassportForMac/scala-2.11.1
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home
netbeans_jdkhome="Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home"

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From http://wiki.netbeans.org/MacOSXEnvForApp page:

1. Create a new directory and page ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
2. Add following snippet to it

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>SCALA_HOME</key>
    <string>/Volumes/MyPassportForMac/scala-2.11.1</string>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/full/path/of/your/scala/home/bin</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**Edit**

For OS X Lion or above, edit the file

```
/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans\ 8.0.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/bin/netbeans
```

and add following

```
export SCALA_HOME=/Volumes/MyPassportForMac/scala-2.11.1
```